How to resolve node modules proxy issue?
I'm Not able to install node_modules and its showing you are behind a proxy
Error:
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET

failed, reason: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'


Issue Resolved
node -v
npm -v
nvm -v
npm ping
npm doctor
rm -rf node_modules
npm cache clean --force 

OR

C folder >> users >> Saiprasad >> AppData >> Roming >> npm >> delete npm cache file

npm whoami 
npm login 
npm whoami
npm config get registry
npm config get registry

If you are installing packages from private registry like JFrog then
npm config set registry <your npmrc file url>

If you are installing packages from npm then
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/

Check status:
git config --get user.email
git config --get user.name
git config --list --show-origin
git config --list

Set:
git config --global user.name "John Doe"
git config --global user.email johndoe@example.com
now do npm i


If still it is not working connect to different WIFI Network
This issue might me related to firewall, try to stop and do npm i
again

Extra:
npm config set fetch-timeout 60000
npm config fetch-retry-maxtimeout 60000

Ask to IT team if company is is using any proxy network then use that proxy
set your npm proxy using:
npm config delete proxy
npm config delete http-proxy

npm config set proxy http://<proxy.company.com>:
npm config set https-proxy http://<proxy.company.com>:

Example:
$ npm config set proxy http://web-proxy.corp.xyzcorp.net:8080
$ sudo npm config set proxy http://web-proxy.corp.xyzcorp.net:8080

Other commands:
git config --global core.gitproxy gitproxy
git config --global url.https://github.com/.insteadOf git://github.com/
npm config fix

